# Add an element to end of the array in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, list, pandas, dataframe

```
  Feature1                                      Feature2
  [0.0450819672, 0.0450819672, 0.0081967213]    8.236613
  [0.0551181102, 0.0551181102, 0.0078740157]    7.954549
```

I would like to add Feature2 which is of type float64 to the end of Feature1 array.
This is how I tried achieving it but Feature2_1 seems to be an empty column.

```
  df_2['Feature2_1'] = ''
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print row[df['Feature2']]
    value = row[df_2['Feature2']]
    df_2.set_value(index,'Feature2_1',value)
```

Any advice would highly be appreciated !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [99]: df
Out[99]:
                                     Feature1  Feature2
0  [0.0450819672, 0.0450819672, 0.0081967213]  8.236613
1  [0.0551181102, 0.0551181102, 0.0078740157]  7.954549

In [100]: df.Feature1 += df.Feature2.apply(lambda x: [x])

In [101]: df
Out[101]:
                                               Feature1  Feature2
0  [0.0450819672, 0.0450819672, 0.0081967213, 8.236613]  8.236613
1  [0.0551181102, 0.0551181102, 0.0078740157, 7.954549]  7.954549
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The number got added to each element in the existing array instead of being appended at the end. I tried `x["nv"] = x["vector"] + x["feed_type"].apply(lambda p: [p])`, where `x` is the DF. 
One note: `type(x.iloc[0]["vector"])` gives `numpy.ndarray`.